# Android Xamarin Notification builder setWhen not working

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to implement local push notification in Xamarin Forms. I am using DependencyService to get the Android implementation of notification.

Here is the code I am using to push a notification at a particular time:

```
public void SetNotification(DateTime notificationDate, TimeSpan notificationTime)
        {
            long dateInMilli = (long)(notificationDate.Add(notificationTime) - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds;

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context)
                .SetContentTitle("Test Notification")
                .SetContentText("Notification from Xamarin Forms")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                .SetWhen(dateInMilli);

            Notification notification = builder.Build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                        (NotificationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            const int notificationId = 0;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
        }
```

The problem is, notification is showing instantaneously not as per date and time set by `SetWhen(dateInMilli)`.

Answer (score 5):

`SetWhen` is used to display the time you put onto the timestamp of the notification, not to send the notification after X. You'll have to use alarms for that.

Refer to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.AlarmManager/) to learn about that class.